# Wordpress FTP via admin panel slow

Tags: server, ftp

I am trying to delete some plugins via the Wordpress admin panel. Sometimes it deletes the plugin quite quickly, but other times it hangs.

I have access to my server, is there anything I can do to speed the performance up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a shared hosting?

Try rising the php memory limit. That will make wordpress admin go faster and your blog!